# jQuery - How to load the parent element and content, via ajax

Tags: jquery

The following jQuery code will search for content in an external page by an id selector #menu. But it will not pull the parent element that wraps the content, but only the content itself...

```
...
var menus = 'jqmenus/menus.htm';
$.ajax({
      url: menus,
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(data) {
        var $data = $(data);
        var data_topmenu = $data.filter("#menu").html();
      }
 });
 ...
```

How can I pull the content AND the full element that wraps the content?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [**`element.outerHTML docs @ MDN`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.outerHTML)

change this:

```
var data_topmenu = $data.filter("#menu").html(); // this gets you the innerHTML
```

to this:

```
var data_topmenu = $data.filter("#menu")[0].outerHTML;
// for target element html with content inside you need to use outerHTML
```

Answer (score 1):

Use JavaScript's `outerHTML`:

```
var data_topmenu = $data.filter("#menu")[0].outerHTML;
```

Since an id selector always returns a single element, you don't need to worry about element 2, 3 and so forth.